# How to make my MouseListeners work in a deserialized JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, serialization, jpanel, mouselistener

I am writing a program which :

1. Creates a [`JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) that contains some Shape objects which can be [`MouseDragged`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html#mouseDragged%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) around.
2. Saves an object of this class in a binary file with an [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)
3. Retrieves the objects from the binary file (with an [`ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)) and adds it in a [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).

My problem is that after my `JPanel` is retrieved (and therefore deserialized, I take it) and added to my `JFrame`, I cannot `MouseDrag` my shapes anymore. No clickable actions work actually.

My teacher told me that I could fix this by using the [`validate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29) method, although I am not quite sure as to how to do it.

Comment: I don't think it can be done.  The original listeners that were registered with the panel are unlikely to be serialized with the component nor would (IMHO) make sense to do so as much of that is contextual.  A better solution would be to register the listeners or even still devise a solution that does not rely on object serialization

Comment: *"Warning: Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases. The current serialization support is appropriate for short term storage or RMI between applications running the same version of Swing. As of 1.4, support for long term storage of all JavaBeansTM has been added to the java.beans package. Please see XMLEncoder."*

Comment: I don't see why this cannot work, given that you're working all within one version of the JRE.  When you deserialize, you of course create a new object with the same info in it, you don't get back the 'same' object, so you would have to register listeners with the deserialized object after it was created, I would think.  Are you doing that?  You don't give us much information about what you are doing, but I wouldn't expect clickable actions to work unless you did the registration after deserializing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't see a change, is that the listeners of the class (even if serialized, which might be the case) do no have references to the objects they're supposed to be in contact with on the other side. Moreover, they are not being re-attached to the components that they were attached to before serialization.

As an example, the following example wouldn't work with serialization, since the listener does something to 'panel', but there's no way the listener can be "re-attached" to the button after deserialization, as well as be aware of 'who' panel is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private JPanel innerPanel;
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;

    public MyPanel() {
        super(new BorderLayout(10, 10));

        innerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        innerPanel.add(label = new JLabel("PANEL"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        button = new JButton("Remove label");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.remove(label);
            }
        });

        add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }
}
```