# Java MouseListener transient

Tags: java, serialization, mouselistener, transient

How can I make MouseListener to be transient in java?
Say I have:

```
public class PanelClass extends JPanel implements Serializable{
  private int w;
  private int h;
    public PanelClass(int w, int h){
       this.w = w;
       this.h = h;
          this.setSize(w, h);
          this.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
    }       
}

public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements Serializable{
    public MainPanel(){
        setSize(500,500);
    }
}


public class MyClass implements MouseListener, Serializable{
   private ArrayList<PanelClass> panels = new ArrayList<>();
   private MainPanel mp = new MainPanel();

    for(PanelClass panel : panels){
        panel.addMouseListener(this);
        mp.add(panel);
    }

    private void serialize(){
          //SERIALIZE MainPanel
    }

}
```

Now, if I want to serialize MainPanel will return an error about GridLayout no Serializable.

If I don't add the MouseListener to the panel, all OK; will serialize.

I was wondering If this MouseListener can be set as transient, and how?

Thank You.

Comment: I am puzzled. You're wanting not to serialize the `MouseListener`; but the only `MouseListener` here is the class you're trying to serialize, `MyClass`.

Comment: Sorry, was a bad example. I edit the question/code, hopefully this example will be better...

Answer (score 0):

GridLayouts are not serializable.

Regarding the mouse listener - what you'll have to do is remove the listener when you serialize the object, and on your deserialize method, add the mouse listener back.

[How to make my MouseListeners work in a deserialized JPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339481/how-to-make-my-mouselisteners-work-in-a-deserialized-jpanel)

Read the answer there too.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

OK... I solved this by creating a custom MouseListener and declare it as transient. Works like a charm. :)